# Detecting ball collision with a user-added square

Tags: java, collision-detection, line-segment

Basically I have been asked to create a pinball game that fires a ball on to a board and the user can control flippers etc to keep the ball from hitting an absorber with added shapes to act as bumpers to keep the ball in play.

However, I've run in to a little problem with my collisions. The user can click a grid square on the board to highlight it and then use the 'Add Square' button to add a square of height 20 and width 20 to that highlighted square also returning its (x,y) position.

```
public void addASquare(Point p) {
    System.out.println("Add square to point: " + p.x + ", " + p.y);
    Square square = new Square(p.x, p.y, L, L);
    bumperList.add(square);
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(bumperList);
}
```

Once, this has been done I then add Line Segments to the square using the (x,y) coordinates from the use adding the square to prepare for collision detection with a ball.

```
public ArrayList<LineSegment> getLineSeg() {
    ArrayList<LineSegment> lines = new ArrayList<LineSegment>();
    LineSegment l1 = new LineSegment(x, y, x + 1, y); // top
    LineSegment l2 = new LineSegment(x, y + 1, x + 1, y + 1); // bottom
    LineSegment l3 = new LineSegment(x, y, x, y + 1); // left
    LineSegment l4 = new LineSegment(x + 1, y, x + 1, y + 1); // right
    lines.add(l1);
    lines.add(l2);
    lines.add(l3);
    lines.add(l4);
    return lines;
}
```

..and here is the code for the collision detection when the ball hits either side of the square.

```
ArrayList<LineSegment> lseg = sq.getLineSeg();
    for (LineSegment line : lseg) {
        time = Geometry.timeUntilWallCollision(line, ball,
                velocity);
        if (time < minimumTime) {
            minimumTime = time;
            newVelocity = Geometry.reflectWall(line, ball.getVelocity(), 1.0);

            return new CollisionDetails(minimumTime, newVelocity);
        }
    }
```

However, when I run the program the ball just carries on through the square. I think I am overlooking some key detail that I can't seem to solve which is why I'm here, so any help or pointers at all will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Sounds like Gizmoball?

Comment: Yeah, it's Gizmoball. @KonradHöffner I'll post up a minimal working example very soon, I'm in work at the moment and only had access to those snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You say your square has side lengths of 20 units which I suppose is the value of your constant `L` but your line segments only have a length of 1. Try replacing the values of `1` by your constant `L`.